# Using Python - How can I create a new column ("new_col") by returning the value of "colA" if "colA" can be found in "colB"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, calculated-columns

I am stuck on a project.
I am trying to create a new unique column by checking two columns (A & B), if the values in A exist anywhere in B, or the value of B exist anywhere in A return that value, else return an "".
For example, I have;

```
    colA colB
0    x     
1    y     
2         c
3         d
4         x
5    d     
6
```

After comparing colA and colB for the first time, I am expecting something like this;

```
  colA colB new_colA
0    x             x
1    y             y
2         c         
3         d        d
4         x        x
5    d             d
6
```

And the for the second time;

```
  colA colB new_colA new_colB
0    x             x         
1    y             y         
2         c                 c
3         d        d         
4         x        x         
5    d             d         
6
```

I don't know how to go about it using python.
I tried excel where I just used conditional formatting to highlight duplicates.

Comment: why are you reporting 'y' in new_col_A if 'y' is not in B? the logic is not clear

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I am trying to create a list of supported and unsupported models.


The idea is that if a model number in colA (supported) appears in colB(unsupported) then it is actually supported hence the "new_colA"



And the remaining model number that did not appear in "new_colA"(supported) is "new_colB" (unsupported).

This is to create unique model numbers for both categories

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame of the input?

Comment: The output in my question was just an example I created to explain what I am try to do. 
```data = {'colA':['x','y','','','','d',''], 'colB':['','','c','d','x','','']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data);
print(df1)```

Comment: Thanks, I added an update to my answer for empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have NaNs in empty cells, you can use:

```
m = df['colB'].isin(df['colA'])
df['new_colA'] = df['colB'].where(m).fillna(df['colA'])
df['new_colB'] = df['colB'].mask(m)
```

Output:

```
  colA colB new_colA new_colB
0    x  NaN        x      NaN
1    y  NaN        y      NaN
2  NaN    c      NaN        c
3  NaN    d        d      NaN
4  NaN    x        x      NaN
5    d  NaN        d      NaN
6  NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Variant for empty strings:

```
m = df['colB'].isin(df['colA'])&df['colB'].ne('')
df['new_colA'] = df['colB'].where(m).fillna(df['colA'])
df['new_colB'] = df['colB'].mask(m).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
  colA colB new_colA new_colB
0    x             x         
1    y             y         
2         c                 c
3         d        d         
4         x        x         
5    d             d         
6
```